# Tensorflow : Get difference between each row/columns in Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

I have a question on TensorFlow Tensor operation. 
Let's say a tensor `T` is described as the follows.
`T: batch_size x num_frame x feature_size`.

I want a new Tensor, which stores a difference in between consecutive frames. The new tensor will have an output dimension of `batch_size x (num_frame - 1) x feature_size`.

In other words, each frame is subtracted with the previous one.
`[x1, x2, x3, ..., xn] -> [x2-x1, x3-x2, ..., xn - x(n-1)]`.

Is there a good TensorFlow operation to do this? I looked for many functions, but was not able to find one.

Comment: you could create a second tensor of the same length as the first one: `[0, x1, x2, ..., x(n-1)]` and then subtract those two tensors.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Thank you! That is good trick. I will give it a try. I hope gradients get defined properly.

Comment: Let me know if that works.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar It seems like it is working. Thank you!